# Can a SQL table have a symbolic link or alias?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a table called `News` and I want to add `Tutorials`. Rather than create a table called Tutorials I want to just use the News table since the structure is the exact same. Is it possible to rename this table to "Posts", but create some sort of alias or symbolic link so that a table called "News" can still be queried?

I'm trying to avoid having to modify any source code as I have a lot of PHP files and modifying every file that contains an SQL query will be slow and error prone.

I have looked up SQL aliases but they seem like they are temporary things that require me to modify the existing SQL queries.

I am running MySQL on Centos. I have root access to the server.

Comment: I think you just want a foreign key relationship back to the same table.  This is definitely allowed.

Comment: Sounds like *views* might be something you want to look into.

Comment: If you are adding something, why would you be modifying lots of PHP files to do with that table? i.e. why can't you use the existing one? How does the name of the table affect your front end?

Comment: Pretty much a view would do what you want rename current table to Posts and then create a News view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A view perfectly solved the problem. I renamed the news table to posts then created a view with the following query.

```
CREATE VIEW News AS SELECT * FROM Posts
```

This created a virtual table called News. The content of this was the exact same. I added new rows to Posts and they showed up when i ran a query selecting a row from news.